# Загрузка изображений из кэш. Нужна помощь

Tags: android, кэширование

У меня есть чат, в котором напротив каждого сообщения находится аватарка отправителя. Я работаю с Firebase Storage и в данный момент эти изображения загружаются у меня постоянно из интернета,даже если они повторяются.
Мне нужно сделать нейкий кэш,чтобы новые изображения,которых нет на телефоне,подгружались и после загружались из кэша,а не из интернета.
Читал много статей про Picasso Cache и OKhttp, но нормальных примеров так и не нашёл. Помогите мне с этой проблемой
В данный момент загрузка происходит так:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import by.ittech.test_chat.MainActivity;
import by.ittech.test_chat.R;


public class MessageAdapter extends FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> {

    private MainActivity activity;
    private Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "Adapter";
    // Идентификатор уведомления
    private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 101;

    public MessageAdapter(MainActivity activity, Class<ChatMessage> modelClass, int modelLayout, DatabaseReference ref,Context context){
          super(activity, modelClass, modelLayout, ref);
          this.activity = activity;
          this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, final ChatMessage model, final int position) {
        TextView message, autor, time;
        final ImageView photo;
        photo=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.photo_chat);
        message = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        autor = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvUser);
        time = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        try {
            StorageReference myRefImage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(model.getUid()+"/img.jpg");
            myRefImage.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final Uri uri) {
                    try {
                        //URL url=new URL(uri.toString());
                        Picasso.with(context)
                                .load(uri)
                                .into(photo);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            message.setText(model.getTextMessage());
            autor.setText(model.getAutor());
            time.setText(DateFormat.format("HH:mm (dd.MM)", model.getTimeMessage()));
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

           ChatMessage chatMessage = getItem(position);
           if (chatMessage.getUid().equals(activity.getLoggedInUserName())) {
               view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_item, viewGroup, false);
           } else {
               view = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_item_out, viewGroup, false);
           }


        //generating view
            populateView(view, chatMessage, position);
           return  view;

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // return the total number of view types. this value should never change
        // at runtime
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // return a value between 0 and (getViewTypeCount - 1)
        return position % 2;
    }


}
```

С включенным интернетом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С выключенным:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Picasso же сама кеширует изображения

Comment: @UjinUkr то есть используя данный код,все загруженные изображения сразу кэшируются и после загружаются из кэша?Но если это так,то в офлайн режиме у меня изображения не загружаются. Почему так?

Comment: последите за трафиком в режиме онлайн и делайте выводы

Comment: @UjinUkr как это можно сделать?Я в этом новичок

Comment: в Android Studio есть функция мониторинга ресурсов, https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-network.html

Comment: @UjinUkr так по вашей логике мой код должен работать и в офлайн режиме?

Comment: попробуйте оставить просто Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(photo), запустите приложение с инетом, а потом без него. посмотрите работает или нет

Comment: @АндроидАндроид пробовал,не работает. Картинки загружаются только при включенном интернете. Интернет пропадает,картинки не подгружаются.

Comment: @shcherbuk странно, такого точно не должно быть.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид добавил класс и скриншоты

Comment: под дебагом myRefImage.getDownloadUrl() без интернета какое значение вернет?